# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'colour' python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using `Tkinter` on MacOS and its libraries are a little broken, so there is an extension called `tkmacosx` that fixes many bugs.
All goes fine if I run the program from terminal with `python3 file.py` or from VSCode.
Then I tried to install it with `pyinstaller`, goes fine and when running the executable this is the output :

```
from tkmacosx import Button
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "tkmacosx/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "tkmacosx/variables/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "tkmacosx/variables/colorvar.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "tkmacosx/utils/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'colour'
```

I checked and `colour` is a library inside`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (0.1.5)` so I tried to add this library to all python versions because I thought that maybe one of them miss this package and adding it to all would fix :

```
ls /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
```

output :

```
2.7  3.10   3.5  3.9    Current
```

So I added colour to each version running (not running on Current bcz it's not a version ?) :

```
python_version -m pip install colour
```

But I still have the same error. It's like if Python can't find the right module path when launching the executable but if I run it from the interpreter with `python3` or from VSCode all works fine.

Consider I didn't set up an environment, I just created files, classes and solved imports. But I created this `__init__.py` file :

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

Because it solved a previous import problem.